# MySQL query with inline selects is very slow

Tags: mysql, select

I created a long MySQL query with inline selects.

```
SELECT users.*, 

(SELECT plan_payments.month FROM user_plans
    LEFT JOIN plan_payments ON (plan_payments.id = (SELECT id FROM plan_payments WHERE plan_payments.partnerId = user_plans.ownerId AND status = 1 ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC LIMIT 1)) 
    WHERE user_plans.planId = :planId AND user_plans.partnerId = users.partnerId ORDER BY plan_payments.year DESC, plan_payments.month DESC) AS lastPaymentMonth,

(SELECT plan_payments.year FROM user_plans
    LEFT JOIN plan_payments ON (plan_payments.id = (SELECT id FROM plan_payments WHERE plan_payments.partnerId = user_plans.ownerId AND status = 1 ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC LIMIT 1)) 
    WHERE user_plans.planId = :planId AND user_plans.partnerId = users.partnerId ORDER BY plan_payments.year DESC, plan_payments.month DESC) AS lastPaymentYear,

(SELECT plan_payments.month FROM user_plans
    LEFT JOIN plan_payments ON (plan_payments.id = (SELECT id FROM plan_payments WHERE plan_payments.partnerId = user_plans.ownerId AND status = 1 ORDER BY year ASC, month ASC LIMIT 1)) 
    WHERE user_plans.planId = :planId AND user_plans.partnerId = users.partnerId ORDER BY plan_payments.year DESC, plan_payments.month DESC) AS firstPaymentMonth,

(SELECT plan_payments.year FROM user_plans
    LEFT JOIN plan_payments ON (plan_payments.id = (SELECT id FROM plan_payments WHERE plan_payments.partnerId = user_plans.ownerId AND status = 1 ORDER BY year ASC, month ASC LIMIT 1)) 
    WHERE user_plans.planId = :planId AND user_plans.partnerId = users.partnerId ORDER BY plan_payments.year DESC, plan_payments.month DESC) AS firstPaymentYear


FROM users
INNER JOIN user_plans ON (user_plans.partnerId = users.partnerId)
WHERE user_plans.planId = :planId ORDER BY lastPaymentYear DESC, lastPaymentMonth DESC
```

Is this query slow because of the inline selects? Is it possible to optimize?

Thanks!

Comment: Your query is so strange... maybe it's better to formulate a task rather than your attempts to solve it?

Comment: Perhaps this is "groupwise-max"?  See:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a case of "splitting up datetime leads to trouble".

If you had a single `DATE` or `DATETIME` column, couldn't you combine the first two subqueries?  Ditto for the other two.

Can't you also avoid the 2-step process to find the previous row?  That is, instead of first getting the id, simply get the row.

Is there an issue of "maybe there is not a 'previous', so we need `LEFT`?